# I want to see all the comments on my questions... discussion (feature request)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Hi all. My first time on meta SO. Really good idea in the first place. Stack Overflow is quite easily the best site I've found this year! Anyway, to my point / suggestion.

When I'm looking at my questions, I often want to see all the comments, as I feel the comments section of answers are sometimes more important than the actual answer, as they often provide clarification. I have found that actually commenting gets me the answer, where as what people put as the answer may not actually help, as either I didn't explain exactly, or they didn't understand.

My proposal is this...
Have a user setting to allow comments never to be hidden in questions the user asked.
I understand that this could be an issue when the number of comments gets larger. Furthering the idea, I was thing impose a comment number limit, say 10, and then page them (By which I mean split with numbers like at the bottom of the SO homepage). This could be a user set value, with limits up to a reasonable number of say 20, but still allowing the user to select less if they wish.

Even if there was a button at the top of the question which you could click to expand all comments, this would be useful, at least for me.

Any comments, thoughts or further suggestions on this?

First time on MetaSO, hope I have the idea right!

Comment: I know this has been discussed before.  I'm not sure where though.  I'm 100% for it though.

Comment: Ok. Maybe it's time for it to be brought up again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to vote this up just because I like the idea. There has been a lot of back and forth about how the comments are displayed for quite a while now and I think that the only way you are going to please everybody is to have the comment display features set by the individual user. It may not be the most convenient or efficient (if everyone sets it to display everything on load it makes the page requests that much higher in resource usage), but it is the only way to really keep the debate about it settled.

Comment: Thanks. I did have a look round, and it seems the debate has been growing. Just thought I'd give my ideas. I can solve logic issue, just cant design graphics... :(